# How to increment a column that is part of a constraint?

Tags: postgresql

I'm storing a list for each user.

```
username|index|...
john    | 1   |a
john    | 2   |b
john    | 3   |c
jane    | 1   |...
jane    | 2   |...
```

Suppose I were to do an addition for john before his index 2, I have to increment the index so that the new table becomes:

```
username|index|...
john    | 1   |a
john    | 2   |new value
john    | 3   |b
john    | 4   |c
jane    | 1   |...
jane    | 2   |...
```

My solution is to first increment john's index that is greater than or equals to 2; and then do an insert statement.

The problem is that this produces a duplicate error:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET index = index + 1
WHERE username = 'john' AND
    index >= 2
```

This is because I have a UNIQUE constraint on `mytable (username, index)`.

What is the workaround for this?

Comment: I would consider why you are even storing and therefore needing to retrospectively update this value, simply create a view and calculate it on the fly.

Comment: The table *must* define the (changeable) order in some column (here `index`). If only *limited* re-sorting is OK, the old style `Basic` *line numbers* will do it: `index: 10,20,30, ...` with gaps to add new rows. (proposed `double precision` column will behave similar). For unlimited re-ordering an *update* of the  `index` is required. How would you establish the order in a *view* @Stu if no table columns defines this order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that a view would be the best option to handle such kind of index, one way to do it is to have a subquery whose order of indices is inverted, so that older indices are updated first. Relevant is the `FOR UPDATE` clause, that the subquery has to have at the bottom of it.

```
UPDATE tab
SET idx = cte.idx + 1
FROM (SELECT idx 
      FROM tab
      WHERE idx >= 2 
      ORDER BY idx DESC 
      FOR UPDATE) cte
WHERE tab.username = 'john' 
  AND tab.idx = cte.idx;

SELECT * FROM tab
```

**Output**:

| username | idx |
| --- | --- |
| john | 1 |
| jane | 1 |
| jane | 2 |
| john | 4 |
| john | 3 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PxDQiaxdP4GDFJooESQE7/1).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `DEFERRABLE` unique constraint for that to work, because such a constraint will be checked at the end of the statement.

However, it is silly to update many rows when a new one is added. Use a `double precision` column to persist the order, because then you can always insert new values between old ones. Assign integer numbers to the order using `row_number()` when you query the table.