# How to reorder a PostgresSQL table based on a column, when inserting, updating or deleting a row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to reorder a PostgreSQL table based on a column, when inserting, updating, or deleting a row?

Say I have a table `questions`, and I have a column called `questionOrder` (an integer), which sets the order of the questions.

If I want to add a question with questionOrder = 5, and there are already 10 questions in the table, how do I update the order of the existing questions to cater to the new question with questionOrder = 5, i.e. all the current questions with questionOrder = 5 and greater should be incremented by one?

In the same aspect, if I delete a question, how do I reorder the table also?

If there is a more correct approach to designing a table/method of doing so, please do point me in that direction, it would be appreciated.

Essentially, I need a way to reorder the data in a table based on a column whenever that column value is updated, inserted, or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an update followed by an insert:

```sql
UPDATE questions
SET questionOrder = questionOrder + 1
WHERE questionOrder >= 5;

INSERT INTO questions (questionOrder, question)
VALUES (5, 'your new question here');
```

The update shifts questions currently numbered 5 or higher up by one.  The insert then adds the new question at the 5 position.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76305288/4808122) for the discussion if there is a unique constraint on the updated column.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think this approach invites a lot of maintenance complications you can avoid by not actually storing the question order.

Instead, you can store some value that represents the relative order of the questions, and then generate the "proper" order when you query it.
This order can be saved as a `double` so you can always (up to the limitation of `double`'s precision) insert a new question between two existing ones. If this precision isn't enough, you could always go with a version-like string.

Consider having questions 1 through 10:

| question_order | question |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | question 1 |
| 2 | question 2 |
| 3 | question 3 |
| 4 | question 4 |
| 5 | question 5 |
| 6 | question 6 |
| 7 | question 7 |
| 8 | question 8 |
| 9 | question 9 |
| 10 | question 10 |

And now you've decided you have a new question that you want as question 5 and to "shift" all the other questions up. Also, you decided you no longer want question 9.
With this approach, you don't need to worry about rearranging the existing questions - you just insert the new question between the existing 4 and 5, and delete question 9:

```sql
INSERT INTO questions(4.5, 'New question');
DELETE FROM questions WHERE question_order = 9;
```

The actual data, after these DML statements would look like this:

| question_order | question |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | question 1 |
| 2 | question 2 |
| 3 | question 3 |
| 4 | question 4 |
| 5 | question 5 |
| 6 | question 6 |
| 7 | question 7 |
| 8 | question 8 |
| 10 | question 10 |
| 4.5 | New question |

But when you query it, you could create a nicer numerical order:

```sql
SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY question_order ASC) AS num, question
FROM     questions
ORDER BY 1
```

and get the following result:

| question_order | question |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | question 1 |
| 2 | question 2 |
| 3 | question 3 |
| 4 | question 4 |
| 5 | New question |
| 6 | question 5 |
| 7 | question 6 |
| 8 | question 7 |
| 9 | question 8 |
| 10 | question 10 |

Comment: As each insertion after the same item requires a division by two - 1.5, 1.25, 1.125, "up to the limitation of double's precision" means it falls over after 50-odd insertions, which doesn't seem to be that many, you probably want to run something to convert the ordinal values back to integers every now and then. (also your final table has a typo - has two row 5s).

Comment: @PeteKirkham you don't need to cut the range in half, just have something between the two ordinals you want. Need another question between 4.5 and 5? It can be 4.75 as you suggested, but it can also be 4.51. Although the point probably stands - at some point, you're better of using a semver-like string instead of a `double`, depending on how frequently your updates are.

Comment: @PeteKirkham regarding the typo - good catch, thanks! Edited and fixed.

Comment: You can't control where the user wants to edit the list, and the worst case is when the user always adds a question in the smallest gap.  So if your ordinals go 4.5, 4.51, 4.511, 4.5111 then the system runs out of precision after ~16 operations (53 bits * ln(2) / ln(10)).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make a decision either to update the order column in each insert of a new question *or* to predefine gaps and use them for new entries.

I'd say if the volume of the insert is very low the update for each inser (proposed in other answer) is OK.

Only caveat is, if the unique constraint on the *order column* is defined, it must be `DEFERRABLE`constraint - other wise you will be confronted with `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint` in the update e.g. `2`to `3`when `3`already exists.

If you have a *large* volume of new entries, estimate a maximum number of new entries between two existing rows per some period (say a day). Round up the number to the next power of two.

The *idea* behind - you'll use the gaps to insert during the day and **reorganize** at the end of it.

Here an example with the **gap size of 8**.

You'll fill the order column (I call it a `technical_order_idx`) with a sequence `1+ N * power(2,3)`, i.e. `9,17, 25, ...`.

```
create table qtab (
id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
technical_order_idx int,
question varchar(10),
CONSTRAINT tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT unique_order_idx UNIQUE (technical_order_idx) DEFERRABLE
);


insert into qtab (technical_order_idx,question)
(values 
(9,'A'),
(17,'B'),
(25,'C')
);
```

**Access View**

The trick makes that you do not use the table (and the *technical order column*) but an access view with a nice integer order column **plus** helper columns for the new technical indexes for insert *before* and *after* calculated in the *middle* of the adjacent rows (e.g. 13 for insert between 9 and 17).

Hope that the view definition is *self explained*.

```
create view qtab_view as
with qt as (
select 
id, question,
technical_order_idx, 
row_number() over (order by technical_order_idx) as order_idx
from qtab),
qt2 as (
select 
id, question, technical_order_idx, order_idx,
coalesce(lag(technical_order_idx) over (order by technical_order_idx),1) as lag_idx,
coalesce(lead(technical_order_idx) over (order by technical_order_idx),technical_order_idx + 8 /* gap size */) as lead_idx 
from qt)
select 
id, question, technical_order_idx, order_idx, lag_idx, lead_idx,
case when technical_order_idx > lag_idx + 1 /* gap is there */ then 
  (technical_order_idx + lag_idx) / 2
end as idx_before,
case when lead_idx > technical_order_idx + 1 /* gap is there */ then 
  (lead_idx + technical_order_idx) / 2
end as idx_after
```

This is the initial situation in the access view

```
select question, order_idx, technical_order_idx, idx_before, idx_after 
from qtab_view
order by order_idx;

question|order_idx|technical_order_idx|idx_before|idx_after|
--------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------+
A       |        1|                  9|         5|       13|
B       |        2|                 17|        13|       21|
C       |        3|                 25|        21|       29|
```

So if you want to insert a new question after `A` you have to use the `idx_after = 13`

```
insert into qtab (technical_order_idx,question)
values  (13,'D');
```

New state

```
question|order_idx|technical_order_idx|idx_before|idx_after|
--------+---------+-------------------+----------+---------+
A       |        1|                  9|         5|       11|
D       |        2|                 13|        11|       15|
B       |        3|                 17|        15|       21|
C       |        4|                 25|        21|       29|
```

After some inserts the gap is filled - you see it that the `idx_before` or `idx_after` are null - you must perform **reorganization** - it is as simple as an  update of teh column `technical_order_idx` restoring the original gap sizes:

```
update qtab q 
set technical_order_idx = 1+ (q2.rn)*power(2,3) /* gap size = 8 */
from  (select id, 
              row_number() over (order by technical_order_idx) rn
       from  qtab) q2 
where q2.id = q.id
```